# T-SQL Counting Distinct Rows to Include Zeroes as Unique

Tags: t-sql

I have the following test script :

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE (number INT)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (6)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (6)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (6)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (2)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (2)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (0)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (0)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (0)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (0) INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (0)
SELECT * FROM @Test
SELECT count(*) FROM @Test GROUP BY number
```

Results

```
number
6
6
6
2
2
0
0
0
0
0

(No column name)
5
2
3
```

I'm trying to get a count of 7 , i.e. distinct for the 6's and 2's and unique for the zeros?

Comment: Why would you want that result?

Comment: Can you please explain this  " trying to get a count of 7 , i.e. distinct for the 6's and 2's and unique for the zeros"?

Comment: Way to go for supplying a test script. However the requested result is not clear.

Comment: Sorry yes I want to count the 6's as a count of 1, the 2's as a count of 1 and the zeros as a count of 5. So each row containing a zero is classed as unique. So my ultimate result will be just 7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest way I came up with is this:

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT NULLIF(Number, 0)) + SUM(CASE WHEN Number = 0 THEN 1 END)
FROM @Test
```

The [`NULLIF`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177562.aspx) makes the [`COUNT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx) ignore numbers that are equal to `0`, the [`DISTINCT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx) is responsible for counting each number only once, and the [`SUM`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187810.aspx) with the [`CASE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) is calculating the number of `0` records.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure why you would want this but you could do both queries separately and perform a UNION ALL to combine the results.

Test Data

```
CREATE TABLE #TestData (Number int)
INSERT INTO #TestData (Number)
VALUES
(6), (6), (6), (2), (2), (0), (0), (0), (0), (0)
```

Query

```
SELECT DISTINCT
Number
FROM #TestData
WHERE Number <> 0
UNION ALL
SELECT
Number
FROM #TestData
WHERE Number = 0
```

Results

```
Number
2
6
0
0
0
0
0
```

If you want to return the number 7, then just wrap this in an outer query like this;

```
SELECT
COUNT(1) FinalCount
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
    Number
    FROM #TestData
    WHERE Number <> 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
    Number
    FROM #TestData
    WHERE Number = 0
) a
```

Result

```
FinalCount
7
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
DECLARE @Test TABLE (number INT)
INSERT INTO @Test VALUES (6), (6), (6), (2), (2), (0), (0), (0), (0) ,(0)

SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT NewNumber)
FROM (SELECT number, 
             (CASE WHEN number = 0  THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY number) * RAND()
                    ELSE number END) AS NewNumber
      FROM @Test) AS T
```

Output result:

```
7
```

if you will add `GROUP BY [number]` you will receive:

```
number  cnt
0       5
2       1
6       1
```